# Backup DB Django MysqlDump

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Good afternoon, I have an application in Django 1.10 where I need to create a backup of the bd, this copy should be made when the user clicks on a button that will be placed in a template and will download the copy in the Team of the user.

In my views.py I have the following.

```
def backup(request):
    subprocess.Popen("mysqldump -u root -p12345 victimas > /home/proyecto/backup.sql")
    subprocess.Popen("gzip -c /home/proyecto/backup.sql > /home/proyecto/backup.gz")
    dataf = open('/home/proyecto/backups/backup.gz', 'r')
    return HttpResponse(dataf.read(), mimetype='application/x-gzip')
```

But I get the error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: django mysqldump
```

Doing this directly from the console creates the file for me, and check the permissions of the folder.
I appreciate your collaboration

Comment: Have you used "import os" in this views.py?

Comment: if it is imported

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: Yes i used "import os" in the first line `import subprocess, gzip, os`

Comment: Is mysqldump a script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this:

In the Django settings file add:

```
RUTA = '/path/to_tmp/file/'
```

In the views.py

```
import subprocess, gzip
from subprocess import Popen
from victimas.settings import DATABASES, RUTA

def backup(request):
    name = DATABASES['default']['NAME']
    passwd = DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
    user = DATABASES['default']['USER']
    ruta = RUTA

    proc = subprocess.Popen("mysqldump -u "+user+" -p"+passwd+" "+name+" > "+ruta+"backup.sql", shell=True)
    proc.wait()
    procs = subprocess.Popen("tar -czvf "+ruta+"backup.tar.tgz "+ruta+"backup.sql", shell=True, )
    procs.wait()

    fs = FileSystemStorage(ruta)
    with fs.open('backup.tar.tgz') as tar:
        response = HttpResponse(tar, content_type='application/x-gzip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="backup.tar.tgz"'
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) documentation, `Popen` takes a list of arguments. If you pass it a string, it will be treated as the command name - the entire string will be treated as the command, not as a command with arguments.

Split the string argument using:

```
import shlex
command_line = "mysqldump -u root -p12345 victimas > /home/proyecto/backup.sql"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
subprocess.Popen(args)
```